# c++ library reference in linux

Tags: c++, header, reference

Hi I am new to programming in Linux, I was wondering do Linux have any reference document that's similar to MSDN? 
Particularly, I am interested in an offline version of 
C++ Standard Library Reference and any library installed on my computer and I can use it to browse or look up when issuing man or info command.
Also, If I want to know the implementation of a particular header file or a particular function..
what places should I look for? /include , /usr/local/include?

Comment: AFAIK, you can just use `man [function]` and the docs are built in, e.g. `man printf`

Answer (score 3):

Use the `man` utility. Most packages and programming languages have standard manual pages. For example, to find out about `vfprintf`, type `man vfprintf` and you will get a manual page about all the printf variants. Some distributions may not install development manual pages by default; you may need `-dev`, `-devel` or `-doc` packages.

The header files are located in `/usr/include` and `/usr/local/include`.

Answer (score 1):

For the C++ standard library you can download a Devhelp book with a working search index from http://en.cppreference.com. For other libraries there's usually a *.doc package with a Doxygen documentation of that library packaged into a Devhelp book.

Answer (score 1):

For adding reference in devhelp just type

```
sudo apt-get install cppreference-doc-en-html
```

in the terminal, it will add up in devhelp.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your distro, but you should be able to find a package for the libstdc++ documentation, which might suit your needs. This typically installs manpages and HTML doco.

For example, on debian you can `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6-4.6-doc`. This will install HTML in `/usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6-base/libstdc++/html/`

(Adjust for your distro and libstdc++ version of course)